# Combining zip_longest() with comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am trying to output values from two data sources in a FOR loop to be displayed in a table. I have partially succeeded, and it looks like this:

| Customer | Product | Quantity | Customer | Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | Product One | 3 | A001 | Product One | 3 |
| A003 | Product Two | 5 | A003 | Product Two | 3 |
| A010 | Product Three | 21 | A003 | Product Two | 2 |
| A007 | Product Four | 1 |  |  |  |

Both data sources can differ in the number of records, which is why I use zip_longest() at this point, but also the individual values, can occur multiple times. To better detect the differences, I want to do a match and make the output look like this - if possible:

| Customer | Product | Quantity | Customer | Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | Product One | 3 | A001 | Product One | 3 |
| A003 | Product Two | 5 | A003 | Product Two | 3 |
|  |  |  | A003 | Product Two | 2 |
| A010 | Product Three | 21 |  |  |  |
| A007 | Product Four | 1 |  |  |  |

Is that somehow possible to use both - `zip_longest()`, and `==` in the same loop?

```
for x, y in zip_longest(list_one, list_two, fillvalue=object()):
    print(x[0])
    print(x[1])
    print(x[2])
    print(y[0])
    print(y[1])
    print(y[2])
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do some version of `merge` or `join` with duplicate keys. Perhaps consider using `pandas`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not had any experience with pandas yet, but in that case I will do some research in that direction. Thanks for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
import pandas as pd

list_one = [['A001', 'Product One', 3],
       ['A003', 'Product Two', 5],
       ['A010', 'Product Three', 21],
       ['A007', 'Product Four', 1]]

list_two = [['A001', 'Product One', 3],
       ['A003', 'Product Two', 3],
       ['A003', 'Product Two', 2]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list_one, columns = ['Customer', 'Product', 'Quantity1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list_two, columns = ['Customer', 'Product', 'Quantity2'])

# adding this column to distinguish unique rows from the remainder
df1['id1'] = df1.index
df2['id2'] = df2.index

# join only unique rows
df3 = pd.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(cols), df2.drop_duplicates(cols),  how='inner', on=['Customer', 'Product'])
# then add the remainders from two dataframes to df3
df3 = pd.concat([df3, df1[~df1.id1.isin(df3.id1)], df2[~df2.id2.isin(df3.id2)]]).drop(['id1', 'id2'], axis=1)
df3 = df3.sort_values(['Customer', 'Product'])

df3

  Customer        Product  Quantity1  Quantity2
0     A001    Product One        3.0        3.0
1     A003    Product Two        5.0        3.0
2     A003    Product Two        NaN        2.0
3     A007   Product Four        1.0        NaN
2     A010  Product Three       21.0        NaN
```